# ElastcSearch - Get unsorted data while retrieving results using "docvalue_fields"

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to retrieve data using `docvalue_fields` from a `text` field. Below is the mapping:

```
PUT dvtest
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "tokenizer": {
          "nl-tokenizer": {
            "type": "simple_pattern_split",
                "pattern": "\n|\r\n|\r|\n\r"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "newline": {
            "type": "custom",
            "filter": [
              "trim"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "nl-tokenizer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "indexMapping": {
      "properties": {
        "data": {
          "norms": false,
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "newline",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query to put sample data in index:

```
POST dvtest/indexMapping
{
  "data":"""
  The quick brown fox 
Jumps over the lazy dog
"""
}
```

Query I'm using to retrieve data:

```
POST dvtest/indexMapping/_search
{
  "_source": false
  , "docvalue_fields": ["data"]
}
```

Now, When I try to retrieve data using above query I get the result as shown below. Tokens in data fields are sorted in alphabetical order and I want to retrieve it in order as it is indexed.

```
 "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "dvtest",
        "_type": "indexMapping",
        "_id": "Kp5jNmQBrlmAX-4PVbm9",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
          "data": [
            "Jumps over the lazy dog",
            "The quick brown fox"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

So, my desired result is:

```
...
"fields": {
          "data": [
            "The quick brown fox",
            "Jumps over the lazy dog"
          ]
        }
...
```

I have tried searching on google for help also checked GitHub but couldn't find anything useful!

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: For stored fields order is preserved but for indexed fields order is not preserved.

Comment: @TechnocratSid Won't it increase the size of index?

Comment: @TechnocratSid Is there any other way to achieve this?